# What is [euclidean-geometry] for?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Isn't Euclidean geometry the assumed *default* kind of geometry unless stated otherwise?  What information is added by tagging a question as [euclidean-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euclidean-geometry) instead of just [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)?

I suppose it matters if the question specifically discusses Euclid's axioms, or contrasts with non-Euclidean geometry.  (For example, [What is the modern axiomatization of Euclidean plane geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80930/what-is-the-modern-axiomatization-of-euclidean-plane-geometry) or [Studying Euclidean geometry using hyperbolic criteria](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347/studying-euclidean-geometry-using-hyperbolic-criteria)).  But otherwise, it seems that [euclidean-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euclidean-geometry) and [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) are being used pretty much interchangeably.